# What does this function like macro mean?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I am a relatively good **C** programmer, I love to do research and hate to ask questions, but this particular piece of code is simply troubling. 
It was used with XQueryKeymap, but I don't understand it at all:

```
#define BIT(c,x) (c[x/8]&(1<<(x%8)))
```

What is really troubling me is the `[]` and the  `<<` symbols. 
But if you could verbally say the meaning of the entire thing, I would be really appreciative.

Comment: Am I the only one holding back all urge to edit this and replace `8` with [`CHAR_BIT`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits)?

Comment: I want to go on a parenthesis spree myself.  That macro stinks.

Comment: I hate to agree with you guys, but the truth is that most of the code is sloppy and undocumented, but at least it gets the job done and I (+ many other people) have learned something new.

Answer (score 5):

It's bit packing values into a char array. There are 8 bits per array element (a char array) so the index into the array is defined by `x/8` -- meanwhile the `1<<(x%8)` is shifting a single bit against the 8 bits in the char by the modulus (the remainder of the `x/8`) -- so this macro returns non-zero if bit `x` is set and 0 if it is not.

Answer (score 3):

Ewww.   This macro will fail if `c` is not a derefencable type and `x` is not a integral type.  Plus, no parenthesis makes this even less safe.  Not good code.

It's short hand to convert `x` as a bit number into an array of memory contained within `c`.  The `<<` shifts a mask up to read the bit and the `[]` is to read memory.  It returns 1 if the bit within the array is set and 0 if not - hence the `BIT` name.